# Want to put search keywords into page URL

Tags: php, url, post, get, keyword

I'm trying to get the user input keyword(s) inserted into the results url of the search. 
I got it to work by changing the method=post to method=get but it then breaks the search and I get no results. I've tried changing various things but nothing seems to work, I have therefore reverted back to the original code which is working (minus keywords in the url)

After a search the url is this: `/imagesearch?go`

I would like to be something like: `/imagesearch?kewords+keyword or similar.`

Thanks if you can point me in the right direction.

Here is my original code:

```
<div align="center">  
    <p>Search by keyword..</p>  
     <form  method="post" action="imagesearch?go"  id="search-form">  
       <input  type="text" name="q">  
       <input  type="submit" name="sa" value="Search">  
    </form> </div>


  if(isset($_POST['sa'])){
  if(isset($_GET['go'])){
  if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['q'])){
  $name=$_POST['q'];

  $sql="SELECT  ID FROM Image WHERE Name LIKE '%" . $name .  "%'  Order by Saleable Desc LIMIT 50";

  //-run  the query against the mysql query function

 $result=mysql_query($sql);
   $content .= ' <p><div id="wrapper">';

// Loop 

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $id=$row['ID'];
          $img = new Image($id);
```

Comment: I think this is supposed to be valid PHP? please add a programming language tag.

Comment: Apologies. Have now added the relevant tags, sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
$name=$_POST['q'];

  $sql="SELECT  ID FROM Image WHERE Name LIKE '%" . $name .  "%'  Order by Saleable Desc LIMIT 50";
```

you only get `q` from the POST variables. How is this supposed to work with a GET request?

Also, **NEVER EVER EVER** use user input directly in an SQL query. Imagine `q == "'; DROP TABLE Image;"`! [Whoever has been teaching you website development should have told you *before* even starting explaining how you issue SQL queries.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issues Marcus. I have been teaching myself, in order to improve my website with added functionality. This is not live on the site yet so will be looking into the security issues you mention. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Regarding what you want, this should help.

```
    <html>
        <form method="get">
            <input type="text" name="q">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </html>

    <?php 

        if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
            echo "<p>" . $_GET['q'] . "</p>";
        }

    ?>
```